# CakePHP2.1 remove id in url

Tags: url, cakephp-2.1

I am using cakephp 2.1 and I have written some actions like view, edit and delete.
In url it looks like 'view/1', 'edit/1', 'delete/1', So that I can change the ids in url.
I don't want to change it in url and it should not allow to edit the ids. Please help me to do that. The work will be more appreciable.

Comment: Could you explain yourself a little more? So you want to have no id's in your URLs? Why don't you want id's in your URLs? Are you concerned about security? Or you just want your URL's to look nice?

Answer (score 0):

OK... I think I understand your question. You are concerned that if people can edit the ID's, as they are visible in the URL's, then it will be a security threat?

First, view actions:

You should check on the server-side if the user has permission to view the record with that particular ID. If they don't, then you can give an error. If they do, then let them view it - don't worry about how they got there, whether they edited the ID in the URL or not. If they have permission to view the record, just let them view it.

Second, delete actions:

Again, just like view actions, you should check on the server-side to see if a user has permission to delete the record. If they do, then let them delete it! Don't worry if they edited the ID in the URL. If the user doesn't have permission to delete the record, then your server-side check will stop them, even if they've edited the ID in the URL.

Third, edit actions:

This is slightly more complicated, but still pretty easy. I'll assume you're editing a record with an HTML form, and submitting via POST. OK, so the ID in the URL determines which record to fetch and edit. As with view and delete, you should do a server-side check to make sure the user has permission to edit that item. If they do have permission, then return the form.

Once the form has loaded, the URL showing in the browser is of no importance. The URL which the form submits to, and the data that the form submits, is important. Now, by default, the edit form will store the ID in a hidden input field. A user could change that ID, and thereby change the record they are editing.

To prevent this, use CakePHP's security component. All you need to do is include the component, and CakePHP will automatically put a hash on the form when it's loaded, which it will check again when the form is submitted. If a user has edited hidden input fields, this check will fail, and CakePHP won't allow the edit to go ahead.

Note that to use the security componenent in this way, you must build your forms using CakePHP's form helper (which you probably already are).

And a final note... sometimes people are a bit paranoid about anyone seeing the ID's in their database - and therefore don't want them showing in URL's or anywhere else. But, in almost all cases, there's nothing 'secret' about ID's at all. It doesn't matter who sees them. All they are is a means for your application, and the database, to identify a record. So long as your application is secure, then you should be able to show all your ID's to the whole world, and have nothing to worry about.